# Azure Pipelines: GraalVM Docker image build best practice

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, micronaut, azure-pipelines-yaml, graalvm

I'm currently doing some research on how to use GraalVM in our project which by now contains an array of Micronaut apps.

I've followed this Micronaut article:
https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-kotlin.html
using Micronaut 3.5.2, JDK 17 and Kotlin.

Everything is working as expected on localhost (Ubuntu 20.04) when building the Docker image by using
`mvn package -Dpackaging=docker-native` and running the app using
`docker run --publish 8080:8080 graal-test`

Now I'm trying to figure out how to build GraalVM Docker images in Azure Pipelines without installing prerequisites for every build. There seems to be very little information about how to do this.

I'm able to run a successful build by adding these two script build steps. `task.prependpath` is in effect in next build step, hence two separate script steps.

```
- script: |
    curl -Lo graalvm-archive.tar.gz https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-22.1.0/graalvm-ce-java17-linux-amd64-22.1.0.tar.gz
    tar -xzf graalvm-archive.tar.gz
    echo '##vso[task.prependpath]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/bin'

- script: |
    gu install native-image
    sudo apt-get install build-essential libz-dev zlib1g-dev
    native-image --version
```

Docker image build step.

```
# Build Docker image
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Build Docker'
  inputs:
    goals: 'package'
    options: '-Pgraalvm -Dpackaging=docker-native -Djib.to.image=$(yourImageNameVar):$(yourImageTagVar) -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true --batch-mode'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
```

The resulting image has approx. virtual size 30MiB in GCR, and app startup time is less than 40ms in GKE.

Closest so far is this
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/21735#issuecomment-867134666

> The azure pipelines ubuntu 20.04 images recently added Graal CE
> 21.1.0: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md#graalvm

Unfortunately, the embedded link is broken.

Any hints on how to do this, will be highly appreciated.

**Side-note**

We managed to build 1 out of 5 Micronaut apps tested so far with GraalVM. There seems to be some issues with Kotlin and GraalVM.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the non-broken link:
https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md#graalvm

I hope this helps. I did notice on the issue that the CI pipeline support for GraalVM is not yet in place, but the VMs themselves are available on the Ubuntu image.